# Maximum size of difference sets with a bounded number of prime divisors

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Call a subset $S\subset \mathbb{Z}$ $r$-smooth if the difference set $S-S$ contains numbers whose prime divisors lie in a set $P$ of distinct primes with $|P|=r$. Let $f(r)$ be the maximum size of any $r$-smooth set.

> What is a lower bound for $f(r)$ in terms of $r$?

Comment: Have you been able to compute any values?

Comment: Let all the prime divisors of numbers in $S-S$ be in the (finite) set $P$. Let $p$ be the smallest prime not in $P$. If $S$ has more than $p$ elements, then two of them are congruent modulo $p$, so their difference has $p$ as a divisor, contradiction. So $S$ can't have more elements than the smallest prime not in $P$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So any set $S\subset \mathbb{Z}$ of size $n$ must contain the primes less than $n$ in the prime divisors of its difference set. So if we take the set (1,...n} the difference set contains all prime divisors less than n and cannot contain any other primes since the maximum difference is $n-1$. It seems like this is the extremal example?

Comment: @GerryMyerson In view of your observation it looks like the upper bound might be a more interesting problem perhaps phrased the other way round as "given a set $S\subset \mathbb{Z}$ of size $n$ which is the largest set of primes that can occur as the divisors of the difference set?"

Comment: @GerryMyerson I guess it might be possible to compute the expected size of this over random sets of integers of a given size and maximum difference bounded above?

Comment: @GerryMyerson In fact you can get at least $2n$ if you choose a set of primes $p_i$, $1\leq i \leq n$ with $p_i>n$ then the set $\{0,p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n \}$ must yield at least $2n$ prime divisors.